# Nativescript angular Cannot move app.component.html in to separte folder

Tags: angularjs, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am using nativescript 2.3.0 with angular. I created a starter project with the following command

`tns create projname --ng`

I have the following folder structure

```
├── app
│   ├── app.css
│   ├── app.component.html
│   ├── app.component.ts
│   ├── main.ts
```

In side the `main.ts` file i have the following.

```
import { platformNativeScriptDynamic, NativeScriptModule } from "nativescript-angular/platform";
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    imports: [NativeScriptModule]
})
class AppComponentModule {}

platformNativeScriptDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppComponentModule);
```

Notice that I am importing the `AppComponent` on line `3`

What I want to do is that I want to organize my code so that i have the `app.component` file in a separate folder

As shown below

```
│   ├── pages
│   │   └── app.component.ts
│   │   └── app.component.html
│   ├── app.css
│   ├── main.ts
```

I have changed the `import` in `main.ts` file to follows

```
import { AppComponent } from "./pages/app.component";
```

Moving the file `app.component.html` file give the following error.

```
Unhandled Exception
com.tns.nativescriptException:
Calling js method onCreateView failed
```

Comment: what is your templateUrl in appcomponent? maybe you should change that.

Comment: Yes I figured it out.. I had relative path to the html template..but the path has to be absolute from the root

Comment: or you can use moduleId https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/issues/367 reason :https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-relative-paths.html